# Self referencing LINQ for linked list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of objects that I load in from a table.  The relevant fields are id, timestamp, name, renamedname.  When an object is created and saved to the table the name refers to its name and renamedname is blank.  These objects can be renamed and when they are the old name goes to name and the new name to renamedname.  Many of these objects coexist and get saved to the database in an unknown fashion.  for any object, I need to find to what name they were renamed to.

If we have this data (the times are simplified for here)

```
Id   Time   Name   RenamedName
1    100      A
2    101      B
3    105      A      Z
4    109      C
5    111      Z      Y
6    114      B      M
```

This would result in `A -> Z -> Y`   and  `B -> M`

I don't need the resulting records to be flattened but they have to be easily followed like in a linked list.

Any ideas how to do this in the fastest way?  There will be 100's or thousands of these.  The best correlation I can come up with is if kept track of files and their being renamed.

The whole table is loaded into memory.  The database is sqlite if it matters.  I understand recursion is involved.  This would be LINQ on an set of objects.

TIA

Comment: Using Linq with Entity Framework doesn't support Recursive CTEs, so you'll either need to write a recursive CTE in SQL by-hand, or load the table into-memory and browse it there.

Comment: Hundreds or thousands isn't a lot for a database.  Even a hundred thousand could be loaded into memory if each record is relatively small.

Comment: I do load it into memory into a list or an array but all the records are loaded.

Comment: Wouldn't it be neater, just to have a table that deals with all the previous names? 1 id has many previous names... Instead of a recursive denormalized table

Comment: TheGeneral - this approach has been considered but UPDATES to the table are not possible since the flow of data is batched (collect the data to insert and send it all every X seconds).  Only data inserts are done.